# Pandas: dealing with missing data (missing field)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-cleaning

This is the data that I'm dealing with

```
14922KMSP MSP2006020712081808   0.138 D                 0.083 D     346     3   349    4    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712091809   0.127 D                 0.089 D     357     3    24    4    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712101810   0.123 D                 0.088 D     353     3   342    4    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712111811   0.119 D                  M    M     344     3   329    4    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712121812   0.120 D                  M    M     329     3   280    3    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712131813   0.118 D                  M    M     341     2     6    2    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712331833   0.123 D                  M    M     359     4   338    5    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712341834   0.122 D                  M    M     339     4   346    4    30L60+              
14922KMSP MSP2006020712351835   0.121 D                80000.00       346     3   321    3    30L60+            
14922KMSP MSP2006020712361836   0.118 D                10001.00         5     3     8    4    30L60+
```

The first few are the correct ones.

For problematic data like

```
14922KMSP MSP2006020712111811   0.119 D                  M    M     344     3   329    4    30L60+
```

It is still easy to deal with, since the column is ordered.

But for

```
14922KMSP MSP2006020712361836   0.118 D                10001.00         5     3     8    4    30L60+
```

There is a missing field after `10001.00`, how should I deal with it?

If I do things like

```
df = pd.read_csv("MSP/out.dat", skipinitialspace=True, error_bad_lines=False, sep=' ',
                names = ['stationID','date','vis','day_type','vis2','day_type2','dir','speed','dir_max','speed_max','unknown','unknown2'])
```

The data after the missing field would all shift left by 1 column, can anyone tell me how to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your column separator really exactly one space?

Comment: @DYZ, no, sometimes several spaces.

Comment: Then how could `read_csv` with `sep='  '` work? Is this really how you read the file?

Comment: @DYZ there is `skipinitialspace=True` for escaping additional spaces.

Comment: Is there any pattern to which data can be missing? In that case I'd clean up the data before feeding it to `read_csv`.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Then what tool should I use before clean up the data? I'm just using pandas to clean the data before computation.

Comment: That's why I asked whether you know a pattern. I'd apply that pattern to each row to "regularize" the data and then pass it to `read_csv`. `Pandas` has some support for dealing with missing data, but not necessarily misplaced data.